# Codigniter login works on regular Codeigniter but not Hmvc

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this login script which works great on regular codeigniter  but when I switch it to hmvc codeigniter I start getting an 404 verify not found error. 
I have three controllers which I will list below. This controller verifies the login info.

```
class Verify extends MX_Controller {

function __construct()
 {
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('user','',TRUE);
}

function index()
{
 //This method will have the credentials validation
$this->load->library('form_validation');

$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username',      'trim|required|xss_clean');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
 //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page
 $this->load->view('login_view');
}
else
{
 //Go to private area
 redirect('home', 'refresh');
}

}

function check_database($password)
{
 //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
 $username = $this->input->post('username');

 //query the database
 $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

 if($result)
 {
 $sess_array = array();
 foreach($result as $row)
 {
   $sess_array = array(
     'id' => $row->id,
     'username' => $row->username
   );
   $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
   }
   return TRUE;
   }
   else
   {
   $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
 return false;
   }
   }
   }
```

this is my login controller

```
 class Login extends MX_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
 parent::__construct();
 }

 function index()
 {
 $this->load->helper(array('form'));
 $this->load->view('login_view');
 }   

 }
```

then this is the home controller.

```
 session_start(); //we need to call PHP's session object to access it   through CI

 class Home extends MX_Controller {

 function __construct()
 {
 parent::__construct();
 }

 function index()
 {
  if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
 {
 $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
 $data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
 $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
 }
 else
 {
 //If no session, redirect to login page
 redirect('login', 'refresh');
 }
 }

 function logout()
 {
  $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
 session_destroy();
 redirect('home', 'refresh');
 }

 }
```

then this is my home view.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Simple Login with CodeIgniter - Private Area</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1>Home</h1>
 <h2>Welcome <?php echo $username; ?>!</h2>
 <a href="home/logout">Logout</a>
 </body>
 </html>
```

this is my login view

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
 <title>Simple Login with CodeIgniter</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Simple Login with CodeIgniter</h1>
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
 <?php echo form_open('verify'); ?>
 <label for="username">Username:</label>
 <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
 <br/>
 <label for="password">Password:</label>
 <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
 <br/>
 <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
 </form>
 </body>
  </html>
```

I do not know why going from mvc codeigniter to hmvc would make a difference but something goes wrong. All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you made your routes `$route['example'] = "module/controller/index";` Also make sure you have all controllers and modules Ucfirst example Welcome.php instead of welcome.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All ways number one check is make sure all controllers and models Ucfirst example Verify.php and not verify.php

If you need to use callbacks in HMVC then you need code below

Place this in libraries

```
<?php

class MY_Form_validation extends CI_Form_validation {

function run($module = '', $group = '') {
    (is_object($module)) AND $this->CI = &$module;
    return parent::run($group);
}

}
```

And then add $this `if($this->form_validation->run($this) == FALSE)`

**And also xss_clean not working in codeigniter 3**

Please note the HMVC from here https://bitbucket.org/wiredesignz/codeigniter-modular-extensions-hmvc/downloads only for codeigniter 3

Also make sure your routes are set correct example

`$route['verify'] = 'modulename/verify/index';`

Comment: I found the problem based on your suggestion to make sure my routes were correct I followed your pattern and solve the problem. Thanks